# RxJS keep old and new value on emission

Tags: rxjs, pairwise

I have been trying to get the old and new value in every emission. I have seen the option of using `pairwise` or `bufferCount` but they don't allow to keep the first value.

The goal would to go from:

```
---1---2---3---4---5---
```

To:

```
---null,1---1,2---2,3---3,4---4,5---
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `startWith(null)` to initialize the operator (whichever you use) and then it'll emit on every value:

```
// or bufferCount(2, 1)
source.startWith(null).pairwise().subscribe(...)
```